# apply by() two times with different indices

Tags: r

It's maybe a trivial question but I cant figure out a proper way to do it.

I have my data frame with the disered column in the end

```
data <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("A1", "A10", "A11", 
"A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", 
"A8", "A9"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B1", "B2", "B3"
), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L), .Label = c("C1", 
"C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", 
"C19", "C2", "C20", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C8", "C9"), class = "factor"), 
    Desired = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "Desired"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L))
```

my proposal

```
data$Desired <- do.call(rbind(by(data$C,list(data$A),function (x) as.numeric(as.factor(x))))
```

but I dont know how to apply by() two times (with column B) in order to have directly my desired output. any help?

Comment: @akrun I labelled it in the data (column Desired), do you need an explicit way?

Comment: Could you check if the expected you showed is correct.  `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, DesiredN := {m1 <- paste0(A, C); match(m1, unique(m1))}, B]` especially for the 'B3' values in 'B' column

Comment: thanks, i am not familiar with this package, i will try to understand what you have done

Comment: or just `setDT(data)[,id := rleid(C),"B"]` ?

Comment: Are you only checking the 'C' column for creating the 'Desired'?   then  `with(data, as.integer(ave(as.character(C), B, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x)))))`

Comment: column C conditional on B and A. It's like:  `by(data$C,list(data$A,data$B),function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))` but it does not work

Comment: @akrun do you see what i want?

Comment: @branchwarren  If it depnds on both B and A, then as I said earlier, the Desired values for row 16 would increment by 1

Comment: agree, thanks for your comments and solution, highly appreciated